# Remove Bars with Small Counts from Bar Chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a bar chart from a factor with lots of levels. I would like to exclude factors which have only a small number of occurrences. I can do this by making a new data frame, but is there a way to get ggplot2 to do it internally?

I have tried using limits, ..count.., etc.

Here is an example:

```
#### This has four levels but I would like to remove bins with only one observation ###
df<-data.frame(x=as.factor(c(rep("a",4),rep("b",5),rep("c",2), rep("d",1))))
p<-ggplot(df)+geom_bar(aes(x))

###### This gives the correct thing, but I had to make a new data frame ######
new.df<-subset(df, x%in%levels(df$x)[table(df$x)>1])
p<-ggplot(new.df)+geom_bar(aes(x))
```

Comment: No, `geom_bar` has [no such ability](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html).  You can of course put everything on one line of code using `ggplot(df[x %in% levels(df$x)[table(df$x)>1], ]) + geom_bar(aes(x))`